# Printing on the same line with value returned from Python 2.7 function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using `,` we are able to have several `print` statements write on the same line.

```
print 'hello',
print 'world'
```

**Problem:** When print the value returned by a function, how do I print the values returned by multiple function calls to be on the same line?

The following code prints the value returned by each function on a separate line:

```
import math


def square_root(a):

    x = a
    e = 0.0000001

    while True:

        print x
        y = (x + a/x)/2

        if( abs(x - y) < e ):
            return x

        x = y


def test_square_root():

    for i in range(1,10):

        print float(i),
        print square_root(float(i)),
        print math.sqrt(float(i)),
        print abs( square_root(float(i)) - math.sqrt(float((i))) )

test_square_root()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the

```
print x
```

inside your function.  That's what's causing the line to end "prematurely".

Answer (score 1):

Add a comma on the last print statement in the `test_square_root()` function:

```
print abs( square_root(float(i)) - math.sqrt(float((i))) ),
```

---

Alternatively, you can *yield* each item from the function instead of printing it:

```
def test_square_root():
    for i in range(1,10):
        yield float(i)
        yield square_root(float(i))
        yield math.sqrt(float(i))
        yield abs( square_root(float(i)) - math.sqrt(float((i))) )

for item in test_square_root():
    print item,
```

Comment: The issue is the print statement in `square_root`, not that one.